# Rails params not picking up Dynamic row values on GUI to controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pass values from GUI to rails controller where my GUI consists of table in which rows are generated dynamically by Javascript. I need two static rows and the rest should be generated on customer's demand.

Issue is only the values in static rows are sent in params, Dynamically generated row values are not sent.

Front end Code:

```
<%= render 'shared/page_title', title: "Order Details" %>
<br>
<table id="tabledata">
    <thead>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Tax</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>Item Total Price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="input"></tbody>
    <tbody id="template">
          <%= form_for @order do |f| %>
          <%= f.label :ordertype %>
          <%= f.text_field :ordertype %> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

          <%= f.label :totalprice %>
          <%= f.text_field :totalprice %> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

          <%= f.label :paymentmethod %>
          <%= f.text_field :paymentmethod %>

          <br>

        <tr>
           <td><input name="order[order_placed][][itemname]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="order[order_placed][][quantity]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="order[order_placed][][unitprice]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="order[order_placed][][tax]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="order[order_placed][][discount]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="order[order_placed][][itemtotalprice]" type="text" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><input name="order[order_placed][][itemname]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="order[order_placed][][quantity]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="order[order_placed][][unitprice]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="order[order_placed][][tax]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="order[order_placed][][discount]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="order[order_placed][][itemtotalprice]" type="text" /></td>

        </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
<label id="ActionAddRow">Add Row</label>
<%= f.submit %>


 <% end %>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    var addInputRow = function () {
       var tr = document.createElement("tr");
             function callback(attribname){
                 nameAttributitemname = 
                       "order[order_placed][][" + attribname + "]";

                //create input for itemname, set it's type, id and name attribute
                var inputitemname = document.createElement("INPUT");
                inputitemname.setAttribute("type", "text");
                inputitemname.setAttribute("name", nameAttributitemname);
                //and append it to <td> element and then <tr> 
                var td = document.createElement("td");
                td.appendChild(inputitemname);  
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }

            callback("itemname");
            callback("quantity");
            callback("unitprice");
            callback("tax");
            callback("discount");
            callback("itemtotalprice");

             document.getElementById("template").appendChild(tr);
  }; 

    var addAll = function (){
         addInputRow();
    };

    $('#ActionAddRow').on('click', addAll);
});
```

Server side:

```
Started POST "/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-07 12:57:14 +0530
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"order"=>{"ordertype"=>"", "totalprice"=>"", "paymentmethod"=>"", "order_placed"=>[{"itemname"=>"11", "quantity"=>"", "unitprice"=>"", "tax"=>"", "discount"=>"", "itemtotalprice"=>""}, {"itemname"=>"22", "quantity"=>"", "unitprice"=>"", "tax"=>"", "discount"=>"", "itemtotalprice"=>""}]}, "utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"/YfKgSt/lgDgC2L1Wa0fDdBjY+zTfEBcblp1rB/St89jsmU52pDnbTCwACyy+qiuZhxyVil63FMlOiq2YEUBhA==", "addresses"=>[{"line1"=>"", "line2"=>"", "city"=>""}, {"line1"=>"", "line2"=>"", "city"=>""}], "commit"=>"Create Order"}
  Customer Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" ORDER BY "customers"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("ordertype", "order_placed", "paymentmethod", "created_at", "updated_at", "customer_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["ordertype", ""], ["order_placed", "\"---\\n- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\\n  itemname: '11'\\n  quantity: ''\\n  unitprice: ''\\n  tax: ''\\n  discount: ''\\n  itemtotalprice: ''\\n- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\\n  itemname: '22'\\n  quantity: ''\\n  unitprice: ''\\n  tax: ''\\n  discount: ''\\n  itemtotalprice: ''\\n\""], ["paymentmethod", ""], ["created_at", "2018-01-07 07:27:14.631269"], ["updated_at", "2018-01-07 07:27:14.631269"], ["customer_id", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
```

GUI screenshot passing three rows.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when `document.getElementById("template").appendChild(tr);` is called, all those new `tr` and the containing inputs are appended under the `<tbody id="template"></tbody>`, causing the resulting HTML structure becoming something like this:

```
<tbody id="template">
  <form ...>
    <!-- Static rendered rows -->
    <tr>
      ...
      <input ... />
      ...
    </tr>
  </form>
  <!-- Dynamically generated rows -->
  <tr>
    ...
    <input ... />
    ...
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And a reasonable behavior, those inputs outside the `<form>` tag will not be sent along with the submitted form. You can move the `<%= form_for @order do |f| %>` line, which generates the `<form>` tag, outside of your `<tbody id="template">`, so that the dynamically appended inputs will also be inside the form.

---

More things to be noted:

It seems you had mistakenly wrote an unmatched pair `<%= form_for @order do |f| %>` and `<% end %>` tags, which you placed the start tag inside `tbody` and the ending tag out of `tbody`:

```
...
<tbody>
  <form>
    ...
</tbody>
  </form>
...
```

This is invalid HTML and the browser might assume that you mean:

```
...
<tbody>
  <form>
    ...
  </form>
</tbody>
...
```

Which causes some unexpected behaviors. The start tag and the end tag should always be in the same level on an HTML document.

And some other issues:

1. For semantic correctness, you should consider using `button` instead of `label` for your `ActionAddRow` button, indicating that is something that users can click on.
2. The label and inputs should be placed outside the `tbody` and `table` since it isn't a part of the table.

Here is a nicely structured sample of your `.html.erb` code:

```
<%= render 'shared/page_title', title: "Order Details" %>

<br>

<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :ordertype %>
    <%= f.text_field :ordertype %>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <%= f.label :totalprice %>
    <%= f.text_field :totalprice %>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <%= f.label :paymentmethod %>
    <%= f.text_field :paymentmethod %>

    <br>

    <table id="tabledata">
        <thead>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
            <th>Tax</th>
            <th>Discount</th>
            <th>Item Total Price</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="input"></tbody>
        <tbody id="template">
            <tr>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][itemname]" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][quantity]" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][unitprice]" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][tax]" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][discount]" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][itemtotalprice]" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][itemname]" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][quantity]" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][unitprice]" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][tax]" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][discount]" type="text" /></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][itemtotalprice]" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button id="ActionAddRow">Add Row</button>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This helped me